# JS or TS - Getting the keys of a interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

Say I have an interface like:

```
export interface Album{
    id: string,
    code: string,
    title: string,
    description: string,
    publisher: string,
}
```

(It's actually quite long - I've just simplified here).
Anyhow, I want to create an object like:

```
const columnSpecs = {
        "id": {  "title": "ID", "width": 300 },
        "code": { "title": "Code", "width": 150 },
        "title": { "title": "Title", "width": 150 },
        "description": { "title": "Description", "width": 150 },
        "publisher": { "title": "Publisher", "width": 150 },
};
```

Now at the moment I'm writing `columnSpecs` myself, however if that interface changes I need to update the object `columnSpecs`.

Is there anyway to pull out the interface key so I can iterate through whatever interface I have then make the object myself?

Thanks.

Comment: interface exists only at compile time, so no - you can't get its keys at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.keys` to extract the keys:

```
Object.keys(albumVar).forEach(key => {...});
```

Comment: What's `albumVar`?

Comment: Your variable of type `Album`.